# How can I change the width of a column in a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that has 4 columns each one 150dp wide. For a given row, if the text in the first column is "desc" then I want that row to have the first column at 150dp wide, second column at 450dp wide, and the last 2 columns to be basically 0. Is it possible to do this. Thanks.

Comment: People volunteer their time to help you, you should "repay" them by going through your previous questions to accept the best answers and upvote any useful ones. As for this question, you can use a custom Adapter that implements two different row layouts and load the appropriate layout for each query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The clue you gave me is very helpful. I did not realize that one gets a reward when I select the best answere. I will go to the previous questions and do so. Sam, thanks again.

Comment: Thank you (from all of us) for doing that. Did you solve this question entirely or do you still need help? I can provide a more detailed answer if necessary.